# Why I am getting the NGINX welcome page instead of my Django application

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have deployed my Django Application on a VPS server. I have configured NGINX and uWSGI server.

Here is my Nginx configuration

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
    upstream django {
         server unix:///root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole.sock; # for a file socket
        #  server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    }

    # configuration of the server
    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      8000;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name my_public_IP_address; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        charset     utf-8;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
        alias /root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/media;  
        }

        location /static {
        alias /root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/static; 
        }

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/uwsgi_params; 
        }
    }
```

Here is my mysite_uwsgi.ini file

```
# mysite_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole
# Django's wsgi file
module          = project.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /root/my_project/venv

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
# chmod-socket    = 664
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

When I am running the Django application with uwsgi and nginx by using this command:

```
uwsgi --socket ProjetAgricole.sock --module ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole.wsgi --chmod-socket=664
```

I am getting this output as a result of the command:

```
(venv) root@vmi851374:~/PIDC/ProjetAgricole# uwsgi --socket ProjetAgricole.sock --module ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole.wsgi --chmod-socket=664
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.20 (64bit) on [Sun Apr 24 18:57:17 2022] ***
compiled with version: 9.4.0 on 17 April 2022 18:54:03
os: Linux-5.4.0-105-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 7 18:49:24 UTC 2022
nodename: vmi851374.contaboserver.net
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole
detected binary path: /root/my_project/venv/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 31601
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address ProjetAgricole.sock fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08)  [GCC 9.4.0]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55d5d758ada0
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72904 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 327968, cores: 1)
```

The content of /root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/uwsgi_params is:

```
uwsgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
uwsgi_param PATH_INFO $document_uri;
uwsgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
```

When I run my application via the web browser it is displaying the NGINX welcome page instead of my project home page which is supposed to appear.

Are there any mistakes in the configurations files?

Please assist

[image]

Comment: what is content of your `/root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/uwsgi_params` and is you actually hosting your project in real `/root/` folder?

Comment: @user973254, I have added the content of uwsgi_params file. About the /root/ folder, it is the real hosting folder

Comment: it is actually very bad idea to host anything from `/root/` folder. And you need to watch your `acces.log` and `error.log` to get actual path nginx uses as `root` directive.

Comment: Where have you put your nginx configuration file? Have you reloaded nginx after putting it there? Also the nginx configuration you have shown us in incomplete - show us the whole `server` block.

Comment: Dear @user973254, here is the error path log. 2022/04/25 05:07:03 [crit] 330126#330126: *83 connect() to unix:///root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 103.203.57.20, server: 173.249.8.237, request: "GET / H>
2022/04/25 07:30:11 [crit] 330126#330126: *91 connect() to unix:///root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 193.124.7.9, server: 173.249.8.237, request: "GET http:>

Comment: @MohamedAbdillah Yes, as I said, `connect() to unix:///root/PIDC/ProjetAgricole/ProjetAgricole.sock failed` **(13: Permission denied)** - you need to stop using `/root/` path for anything unrelated to root user and his privileges

Comment: @MohamedAbdillah glad to help you, mark your question closed then, please